# how to add self-closing tag to an element in xml?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

There are plenty of information for how to avoid self-closing tag for an XElement in C# on the web, but I want to do is the reverse one. I give a value to an XElement, and also want to see a self-closing tag in the output xml.

This is my code:

```
XElement myElement = new XElement("MyItem",
    new Attribute("value1", "test1),
    new Attribute("value2", "test2),
    new Attribute("value3", "test3)
);
```

This is what I got now in the output xml file:

```
<MyItem value1="test1" value2="test2" value3="test3">

</MyItem>
```

What I want is:

```
<MyItem value1="test1" value2="test2" value3="test3" />
```

How to do it? Thanks.

**Additional information:**

I am using C# with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Is MyItem a UserControl that you've defined?

Comment: Does your code even compile?

Comment: Yes, but I want a self-closing tag in the output xml, but it gives me explicit closing tag since the string value of the item is not empty.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what is the problem here. Your code (after some minor fixes) produces self-closing tag for me :

```
XElement myElement = new XElement("MyItem",
                                  new XAttribute("value1", "test1"),
                                  new XAttribute("value2", "test2"),
                                  new XAttribute("value3", "test3")
                    );
Console.WriteLine(myElement.ToString());
```

Output :

```
<MyItem value1="test1" value2="test2" value3="test3" />
```

Comment: I don't know what is the difference, but I didn't get a self-closing tag for me.

Comment: @E_learner: You do know this code is different to the code you provided?

Comment: Ok, I got it. It should be "XAttribute". Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly related, but hope it helps someone.
I wanted to removed the self self closing tag. 
That is, what I wanted is

```
<label id="txtInitialTemperatureErrorMessage" hidden="true" class="errorLocal"></label>
```

instead of

```
<label id="txtInitialTemperatureErrorMessage" hidden="true" class="errorLocal" />
```

What I did is simply the following.

Instead of

```
new XElement("label",     new XAttribute("id", "txt" + x.Key + "ErrorMessage"), new XAttribute("hidden", "true"), new XAttribute("class", "errorLocal")),
```

I did

```
new XElement("label", "", new XAttribute("id", "txt" + x.Key + "ErrorMessage"), new XAttribute("hidden", "true"), new XAttribute("class", "errorLocal")),
```

I had added a empty string for second parameter. The second parameter is for content.