# Regular Expressions XML

Tags: regex, xml, oracle

I would like to change the format for writing empty node in an XML file.

```
<products>
   <product>
     <id class="123"/>
     <title><font>TITLE</font><size/></title>
     <name/>
     <category>
       <id/>
     </category>
   </product>
</products>
```

I want to get:

```
<products>
   <product>
     <id class="123"></id>
     <title><font>TITLE</font><size></size></title>
     <name></name>
     <category>
       <id></id>
     </category>
   </product>
</products>
```

Comment: The meaning should be identical. Do you have any particular reason? Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes I have a reason, API in PrestaShop doesn't understand <foo/>, it only understands <foo></foo>

Comment: Would this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55097496/121309 ?

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem, because I have an XML file ready, I don't create this file

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55097496/121309) I created this C# code:

```
var source = XElement.Parse(@"<products>
   <product>
     <id class=""123""/>
     <title><font>TITLE</font><size/></title>
     <name/>
     <category>
       <id/>
     </category>
   </product>
</products>");

foreach (var node in source.DescendantNodes()      // loop through all nodes
    .Where(e => e.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) // find elements
    .Where(e => !((XElement)e).HasElements))       // that have no children
{
    XElement elt = (XElement)node;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(elt.Value))
    {
        // when the value is null or empty, explicitly set to empty string
        elt.Value = string.Empty;
    }
}

string sourceWithExplicitCloseTags = source.ToString();
```

which produces this XML:

```xml
<products>
  <product>
    <id class="123"></id>
    <title>
      <font>TITLE</font>
      <size></size>
    </title>
    <name></name>
    <category>
      <id></id>
    </category>
  </product>
</products>
```

Comment: OK, I'll check if I can do it in ORACLE (because I have to do it in ORACLE with ORACLE functions to XML;)

Comment: @TomaszTomzik That would have been important info to add to your question. I've added a tag

Comment: so I suggested solving the problem by "regular expression"

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't generate with oracle (or I don't know how) empty tags <foo></foo>